# how to change background when validate fails

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I would like to change the background when form validation fails:

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
     <input id="myID" required>
     <button id="myButton">OK</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
 $('#myForm').validate({

    errorClass: 'noValidate'
 });
```

css:

```
.noValidate{ 
     background: #ffdddd; 
}
```

but it doesnt work.

What are I missing?

As Rory McCrossan said, the problem was another css style. That code is correct

Comment: Is the class being applied?

Comment: What  you have should work. Do you have any other CSS rules over-riding the background colour?

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/6udvf9cx/

Comment: validate function exists if you import jquery.validate.js in your html

Comment: use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` in this case

Comment: You want to change the background of what?  The input? the message? the form?  the whole page??